# Form with Text and Submit give wrong output value

Tags: html, forms

I have a little problem with my HTML Form and can't resolve it.

I have the following form:

```
<div class="list-search">
   <form action="" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
   <input type="submit" value="Search">
</div>
```

It works without any problem, but it appends to the URL another value that is not present.
To give an example, the correct URL will be "SITE_URL/?search=VALUE" but from nowhere it become "SITE_URL/?search=VALUE&cat=-1" with &cat=-1 that I don't know how to remove.

I've got around the problem temporarily with a redirect removing the wrong part, but it's not so elegant nor optimized. I hope someone could help, thanks!

P.S. My bad, `</form>` was in the wrong position, all okay now...

Comment: Where is the form tag closed?

Comment: ...that's exactly what was the problem, I was rewriting some code and found a lonely `</form>` many lines after... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close the form tag. That's why it shows some other input's value too because you must have that somewhere else in the code and the form takes that to be the part of it too. So use this, it will work -

```html
<div class="list-search">
  <form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've updated the question because I've found a random `</form>` in the wrong position, obviously causing the problem...